# What's the order of Saint Seiya anime series and movies?

Tags: saint-seiya

I wanted to watch Saint Seiya, but I found on Wikipedia that there are many series that make up the Saint Seiya franchise. So what's the order of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **main series** is [**Saint Seiya**](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1254/Saint_Seiya) which is an adaptation of first part of the homonymous manga by Masami Kurumada.

The second part of that manga was later adapted in three different series of OVAs which tells about the Holy War fought at the end of the 20th century between Athena and Hades:

1. Hades: Chapter Sanctuary
2. Hades: Chapter Inferno
3. Hades: Chapter Elysium

This is the core of the story and is set in the 1990s. In the same period of time are set the four OAVs: **Jashin Eris**, **Kamigami no Atsuki Tatakai**, **Shinku no Shounen Densetsu** and **Saishuu Seisen no Senshi-tachi**.

Then there are the **prequels**:

- **Episode G** is set a brief time before the main story and tells stories about the youth of the Gold Saints.
- **Next dimension** is both a prequel and a sequel (it involves time travel): it is written by the same author of the original story and it tells about the Holy War fought 243 years before the main story.
- **Lost Canvas** is an alternative prequel (who was adapted by into a two series of OVAs) written by another author, which tells an alternative version of the Holy War fought 243 years before the main story.

The **sequels** are:

- **Next dimension** (see above)
- **Soul of Gold** is set in parallel to the ending of the main story and tells about the Gold Saints who are resurrected after their sacrifice at the end of the main story.
- **Tenkai-hen** an OVA set after the ending of the main story and sees as the main antagonist the God Artemis.
- **Omega** is set 25 years after the main story and tells about the "new generation" of Saints who will have to fight agains Mars and his warriors.

There is also a **spin-off**, called **Saintia Sho** set more or less in the middle of the main story, where the main antagonist is the Goddes Eris.

The following is a scheme showing how the various series are related.

[image]

Comment: I should add that canonicity in Saint Seiya is extremely wishy-washy. If you're going purely by Kurumada's timeline, it would pretty much only be his Mangas, both the original and Next Dimension. Anime-wise, you have all that plus the Asgard arc (and by extension Soul of Gold) which was completely made for the anime, the movies, including Tenkai-hen and Omega. Really, each fan's definition of what's canon or not can vary. I hear some fans consider Lost Canvas to be more canon than ND due to personal preference, since the two series greatly contradict each other.